# Constructor must explicitly initialize the member which does not have a default constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, instantiation

I keep getting this error when compiling. I'm not sure whether it's something wrong with my template constructor or how I'm inserting the type 'handler' into the doubly linked list.

```
./ListNode.h:14:3: error: constructor for 'ListNode<Handler>' must explicitly
      initialize the member 'data' which does not have a default constructor
                ListNode(T d);
                ^
./doublyLinked.h:70:25: note: in instantiation of member function
      'ListNode<Handler>::ListNode' requested here
        ListNode<T> *node= new ListNode<T>(d);
                               ^
simulation.cpp:56:20: note: in instantiation of member function
      'DoublyLinkedList<Handler>::insertBack' requested here
                                                handlerList->insertBack(*handler);
                                                             ^
./ListNode.h:9:5: note: member is declared here
                T data;
                  ^
./handler.h:4:7: note: 'Handler' declared here
class Handler
      ^
```

Heres the github right here for the full code ->
https://github.com/Cristianooo/Registrar-Simulator

Answer (score 0):

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists

Don't write

```
template <class T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode(T d)
{
    data=d;
    next=NULL;
    prev=NULL;
}
```

because `T data` is not properly constructed when the `ListNode<T>` constructor runs.

Instead write

```
template<class T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode(const T& d) : data(d), next(0), prev(0) {}
```

assuming `T` has a copy constructor.

In C++11 you should use `nullptr` and additionally provide a method to emplace the data without copying using an rvalue reference.

```
template<class T>
ListNode<T>::ListNode(T&& d) : data(std::move(d)), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
```

Additionally, in C++11 you may also want to mark these constructors as `explicit` to avoid potential implicit conversions from `T` to `Node<T>`.

```
template<class T>
class ListNode {
public:
    explicit ListNode(const T& data);
    explicit ListNode(T&& data);
};
```

Your code also defines non-inline code in a `.h` file, which may cause ODR violations later.